# Like button on the list, press effect is always on first one

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

My problem is that:

1. I can't display buttons that have already been selected ("vote up" or "vote down") - variables in the view code.
2. When I press the button on the last comment, e.g. "vote up". - the 'vote up' button on the first comment is highlighted - which is not sorted out.

The problem may be that this is a list and additionally in a view, where the object is already a Post model.

My code is below.

Here is models of Post and Comment

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextUploadingField()
    votes_up = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='up_votes')
    votes_down = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='down_votes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def total_vote_up(self):
        return self.votes_up.count()

    def total_vote_down(self):
        return self.votes_down.count()


class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    text = RichTextUploadingField()
```

Here is detail view where I would like to check if comment is liked or not. I pass to context variables.

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView, FormMixin):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    model = Post
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        is_voted_up = False
        is_voted_down = False

        comments = self.get_object().comments.all()
        for comment in comments:
            if answer.votes_up.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                print(answer)
                is_voted_up = True
                print(is_voted_up)
            if answer.votes_down.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                is_voted_down = True

        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = comments
        context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={'post': self.get_object(), 'author': self.get_user()})
        context['is_voted_up'] = is_voted_up
        context['is_voted_down'] = is_voted_down
        return context
```

Below are urls and views to vote up or vote down:

```
url(r'^voteup/$', login_required(CommentVoteUpView.as_view()), name='comment_voteup'),
url(r'^votedown/$', login_required(CommentVoteDownView.as_view()), name='comment_votedown'),


class CommentVoteUpView(generic.View):
    def post(self, request):
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=request.POST.get('id'))
        is_voted_up = False
        if comment.votes_up.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            comment.votes_up.remove(request.user)
            is_voted_up = False
        else:
            comment.votes_up.add(request.user)
            is_voted_up = True
        context = {
            'comment': comment,
            'is_voted_up': is_voted_up,
            'total_vote_up': comment.total_vote_up(),
            }
        if request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string('voteup_section.html', context, request=request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})


class CommentVoteDownView(generic.View):
    def post(self, request):
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=request.POST.get('id'))
        is_voted_down = False
        if comment.votes_down.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            comment.votes_down.remove(request.user)
            is_voted_down = False
        else:
            comment.votes_down.add(request.user)
            is_voted_down = True
        context = {
            'comment': comment,
            'is_voted_down': is_voted_down,
            'total_vote_down': comment.total_vote_down(),
            }
        if request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string('votedown_section.html', context, request=request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

below is jquery code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(event){
                $(document).on('click', '#voteup', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "{% url 'comment_voteup' %}",
                        data: {'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#voteup-section').html(response['form'])
                            console.log($('#voteup-section').html(response['form']))
                        },
                        error: function(rs, e){
                            console.log(rs.responseText);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(event){
                $(document).on('click', '#votedown', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "{% url 'comment_votedown' %}",
                        data: {'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#votedown-section').html(response['form'])
                            console.log($('#votedown-section').html(response['form']))
                        },
                        error: function(rs, e){
                            console.log(rs.responseText);
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

last but not least html part - only comment part and buttons from votes section:

```
          {% if comment %}
              <h5>{{ comment.count }} Answers:</h5>
              <hr>
              {% for comment in comments %}
              <div class="media mb-4">
                <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">{{ comment.author }}</h5>
                    <p>{{ comment.text|safe }}</p>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                        <div id="voteup-section">
                            {% include 'voteup_section.html' %}
                        </div>
                        <div id="votedown-section">
                            {% include 'votedown_section.html' %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% if not forloop.last %}
              <hr>
              {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
```

Button to vote up:

```
<form action="{% url 'comment_voteup' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" id="voteup" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}" {% if is_voted_up %} class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Voted up! {% else %} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Vote up!{% endif %} <span class="badge badge-light">{{ total_vote_up }}</span></button>
</form>
```

I would like you to be able to vote for every comment on "vote up" or "vote down" and to know which button was chosen or "vote up" or "vote down".

Comment: ID should be unique. If you have multiple objects with the same ID, browser only picks up the first one. That is why it's not working. Instead of using `id`, use `class`. And in your JS code, instead of selecting by id - `'#voteup'`, select by class - `'.voteup'` (or whatever class name you give the vote button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DOM has several elements with the same `id` any code like:

```
$(#some_repeated_id)
```

will reference the first element with `id=some_repeated_id`. Said that, I'll suggest a couple of changes:

```
<!-- div id="voteup-section" -->
<div id="voteup-section-{{ comment.id }}">
```

and in the form

```
<!--button type="submit" id="voteup-{{ comment.id }}" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}" {% if is_voted_up %} class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Voted up! {% else %} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Vote up!{% endif %} <span class="badge badge-light">{{ total_vote_up }}</span></button-->

<button type="submit" id="voteup-{{ comment.id }}" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}" {% if is_voted_up %} class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Voted up! {% else %} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Vote up!{% endif %} <span class="badge badge-light">{{ total_vote_up }}</span></button>
```

And then handle the correct button being clicking in your javascript, perhaps using a `data-*` attribute.